# Деплой телеграм бота на aiogram с webhook на ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, telegram-bot, aiogram, webhook

Пытаюсь запустить командой sudo python3 bot.py, запускается нормально
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но как только боту поступает какая-либо команда, то сразу возникает ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Достаточно внимательно почитать текст и найти ответ, что сервер вам выдает 400 ошибку.